# How to test an enterprise antivirus

Tags: antivirus

In our enterprise we have an antivirus solution but we are evaluating to pass to another solution. What could be a good strategy to test on our enviroment what antivirus solution works better?

Comment: Have you looked up the independent testing organisations that rate this type of thing on a regular basis? One of the things that you also need to consider is that there are many different methods of AV, and they are not all comparable. You also need to get very specific about what you mean by "works better". What do mean by "working"? What's your desired outcome? You migth think that that is obvious, but once you start to define it, you will find that its not.

Comment: I've looking almost every comparison on internet (independent or not). Mostly of them show different result for this reason my idea was to have a test in our enviroment. For "works better" I mean the solution that block more threats.

Comment: And you've discovered the problem: there is no way to do a straightforward comparison. You can throw known viruses at different products, but if ***you*** can get your hands on them, then whatever you're testing has already devised a way to detect it too. All products will likely have 100% detection rate for your tests. You want to know if the products will block ***future*** threats. That's far more difficult to test for.

Comment: *"For "works better" I mean the solution that block more threats"* - just cut all network traffic and it will block more threats. In other words: a good solution should not just block threats but it should let you work, have a low number of false positives, don't cause any critical problems by its own etc. As schroeder already said: better rely on external and independent tests.

Comment: Both solution I'm comparing are enterprise solution that have more o less same impact on user activity. The difference is in technology used to block threat. Of course in the concept of blocking threat is considered also the concept of false positive.

Comment: https://secure2.sophos.com/en-us/medialibrary/Gated-Assets/white-papers/endpoint-security-testing-guide.pdf might be worth a read.